# Cannot bind to System.String in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm having this issue where I want to display three string variables in a stackLayout in my Xamarin app. Whenever I run the code and click on "Get" I get the following message in my log output: *[0:] Binding: "..." can not be converted to type 'System.String'*.

This is my model code:

```
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Test1.Models
{
  class Game
   {
     [PrimaryKey]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string GameNaam { get; set; }
     public string GameGenre { get; set; }
     public string GameRelease { get; set; }

     public override string ToString()
     {
        return this.GameNaam + " " + this.GameGenre + " " + this.GameRelease;
     }
   }
 }
```

And this is the views code to get the input the user entered on another page:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Test1.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Test1.Views
{
  public class GetAllGamesPage : ContentPage
  {
    private ListView _listView;
    string _dbPath = 
    Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), 
    "myDB.db3");

    public GetAllGamesPage()
    {
        this.Title = "WishList";
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);

        StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();

        _listView = new ListView();
        _listView.ItemsSource = db.Table<Game>().OrderBy(x => x.GameNaam).ToList();
        stackLayout.Children.Add(_listView);

        Content = stackLayout;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What line is the error caused on? This? `string _dbPath = 
  Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), 
    "myDB.db3");`

Comment: No it doesn't give an error. It simply displays nothing when I click on "Get". It only outputs the following in my program (after clicking on "get"): [0:] Binding: GameName:ResidentSleeper, GameGenre:FPS, GameRelease:20/04/2019 can not be converted to type 'System.String'

Comment: Those input values are from another page...

Comment: Did you try to add an implicit conversion between Game and string ? In your class `Game` add the following: `public static implicit operator string(Game g) => g.GameNaam + " " + g.GameGenre + " " + g.GameRelease;` The previous line adds an implicit conversion from Game to string. You may try to add another implicit conversion from string to Game.

Comment: No I haven't how would I do that? I'm new to all of this.

Comment: @Felix, see the edited comment.

Comment: none of the code you posted is actually doing any binding?  You need to post the relevant code.

Comment: @Felix, Glad that it did the trick! Going to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an [implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) from the `Game` type to the `string` type.

```cs
public static implicit operator string(Game g) => g.GameNaam + " " + g.GameGenre + " " + g.GameRelease;
```

You can also use string interpolation to make it more readable:

```cs
public static implicit operator string(Game g) => $"{g.GameNaam} {g.GameGenre} {g.GameRelease}";
```